# Suddenly remote NFS folders will not auto-mount when booting up

Tags: server, mount, nfs

I have a headless server running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS with all latest updates. It is sharing a number of folders using NFS.

Contents of may /etc/exports file:

```
# add folders we want to share through NFS
/mnt/raiddisk/john       (rw)
/mnt/raiddisk/vm        (rw)
/mnt/raiddisk           (rw)
/mnt/raiddisk/filecopy  (rw)
/mnt/raiddisk/movies    (rw)
/mnt/raiddisk/jane     (rw)
/mnt/raiddisk/svn       (rw)
/home/vboxuser2         (rw)
/var/www/server.johndoe.home/public_html               (rw)
/home/john       (rw)
```

My client machines (2) are running Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS with all the latest updates. And both are suddenly unable to mount the NFS shared folders at boot.

Here are only the relevant contents of my /etc/fstab file:

```
# mount the NFS folders from the server
192.168.1.20:/mnt/raiddisk/john                          /mnt/john                                        nfs     auto,defaults   0       0
192.168.1.20:/mnt/raiddisk/vm                           /mnt/vm                                         nfs     auto,defaults   0       0
192.168.1.20:/home/vboxuser2                            /mnt/vboxuser2                                  nfs     auto,defaults   0       0
192.168.1.20:/mnt/raiddisk                              /mnt/raiddisk                                   nfs     auto,defaults   0       0
192.168.1.20:/var/www/server.johndoe.home/public_html  /mnt/server-www                                 nfs     auto,defaults   0       0
192.168.1.20:/home/john                                  /mnt/johnhome                                    nfs     auto,defaults   0       0
```

Up until a few days ago this set up was running perfectly fine. On my client machine the folders were being mounted at boot.

Now however (I assume since a recent update) the folders are not mounted when I boot up the machine.

They will only mount after I manually run the follwing in the terminal:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Here is the output of sudo mount -a -v:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Aug 16 23:40:00 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Aug 16 23:40:00 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Aug 16 23:40:00 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Aug 16 23:40:00 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Aug 16 23:40:00 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.20'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 36461
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.20 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 42598
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Aug 16 23:42:11 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.20,clientaddr=192.168.1.7'
```

On the client machine, when I search /var/log for any NFS related lines I have the following output (I have selected only the most recent entries):

```
/var/log/syslog:Aug 16 13:23:34 ubuntu kernel: [   15.128595] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog:Aug 16 13:23:34 ubuntu rpc.idmapd[875]: main: open(/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs): No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog:Aug 16 21:44:48 ubuntu kernel: [30119.650872] nfs: server 192.168.1.20 not responding, timed out
/var/log/syslog:Aug 16 21:48:00 ubuntu kernel: [30312.356845] nfs: server 192.168.1.20 not responding, timed out
/var/log/syslog:Aug 16 22:55:50 ubuntu kernel: [   15.444005] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog.1:Aug 16 13:04:35 ubuntu kernel: [   15.876127] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog.2.gz:Aug 15 14:00:52 ubuntu kernel: [   17.467940] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog.3.gz:Aug 14 22:12:45 ubuntu kernel: [   14.015935] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog.3.gz:Aug 14 22:12:45 ubuntu rpc.idmapd[898]: main: open(/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs): No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog.4.gz:Aug 12 22:49:49 ubuntu kernel: [   12.920639] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog.4.gz:Aug 12 22:49:49 ubuntu rpc.idmapd[910]: main: open(/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs): No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog.5.gz:Aug 11 21:33:11 ubuntu kernel: [   14.363706] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog.6.gz:Aug 10 21:29:28 ubuntu kernel: [   12.760663] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog.6.gz:Aug 10 21:29:29 ubuntu rpc.idmapd[890]: main: open(/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs): No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Aug  6 20:58:35 ubuntu kernel: [   15.475703] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Aug  7 07:37:22 ubuntu kernel: [   12.183087] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/udev:KERNEL[15.324744] add      /module/nfs (module)
/var/log/udev:DEVPATH=/module/nfs
/var/log/udev:UDEV  [15.325094] add      /module/nfs (module)
/var/log/udev:DEVPATH=/module/nfs
```

I am not sure what I need to check to identify the issue. I have checked user permissions and file permissions, nothing has changed.

I am assuming that there was some NFS related update which has caused my configuration to be incompatible in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still do not know why this suddenly happened. I have found a workaround.

Since running `mount -a` in the terminal mounts the NFS shares, it was suggested to me to add that command to /etc/rc.local and have it run automatically during the boot up.

So edit /etc/rc.local and add `mount -a` before the `exit 0` line.

Now upon starting the client the NFS shares are once again mounted without me having to do anything manually.